# How to change datetime format in MVC 3

Tags: c#

I have code.

Model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bạn hãy nhập ngày tháng năm sinh")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Ngày tháng năm sinh không chính xác, bạn hãy nhập lại")]
    [ValidationHelper.DateFormat(ErrorMessage = "Ngày tháng năm sinh không chính xác, bạn hãy nhập lại")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Display(Name = "Ngày sinh")]
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

View

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Account"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>

            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
}
```

when i input 05/31/2012 => The value '05/31/2012' is not valid for Ngày cấp CMT.
when i input 31/05/2012 =>The field Ngày cấp CMT must be a date.
What happened is that? I am from Viet Nam. My English very bad but please help me! Thanks very much!
My local date format yyyy/MM/dd

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
@item.Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

or you could use the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute on your view model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
pubilc DateTime Date { get; set }
```

and in your view simply:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the `DisplayFormat` to work with `EditorFor`, you need to add the `ApplyFormatInEditMode` as follows:

`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems have a Display Format for your dates:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

if you want 31/05/2012 to be a date, you can change your Display Format to:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```